# Bash - Read Directory Path From TXT, Append Executable, Then Execute

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am setting up a directory structure with many different R & bash scripts in it. They all will be referencing files and folders. Instead of hardcoding the paths I would like to have a text file where each script can search for a descriptor in the file (see below) and read the relevant path from that.

Getting the search-append to work in R is easy enough for me; I am having trouble getting it to work in Bash, since I don't know the language very well.

My guess is it has something to do with the way `awk` works / stores the variable, or maybe the way the `/` works on the awk output. But I'm not familiar enough with it and would really appreciate any help

### Text File "Master_File.txt":

```
NOT_DIRECTORY "/file/paths/Fake"
JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY "/file/paths/Real"
ALSO_NOT_DIRECTORY "/file/paths/Fake"
```

### Bash Script:

```
#! /bin/bash

master_file_name="Master_File.txt"
R_SCRIPT="RScript.R"
SRCPATH=$(awk '/JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY/ { print $2 }' $master_file_name)
Rscript --vanilla $SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT
```

The last line, `$SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT`, seems to be replacing part of `SRCPath` with the name of `$R_SCRIPT` which outputs something like `/RScript.Rs/Real` instead of what I would like, which is `/file/paths/Real/RScript.R`.

Note: if I hard code the path `path="/file/paths/Real"` then the code `$path/$R_SCRIPT` outputs what I want.

### The R Script:

```
system(command = "echo \"SUCCESSFUL_RUN\"", intern = FALSE, wait = TRUE)

q("no")
```

Please let me know if there's any other info that would be helpful, I added everything I could think of. And thank you.

## Edit Upon Answer:

I found two solutions.

#### Solution 1 - By Mheni:

[ see his answer below ]

#### Solution 2 - My Adaptation of Mheni's Answer:

After seeing a Mehni's note on ignoring the `"` quotation marks, I looked up some more stuff, and found out it's possible to change the character that `awk` used to determine where to separate the text. By adding a `-F\"` to the `awk` call, it successfully separates based on the `"` character.

The following works

```
#!/bin/bash

master_file_name="Master_File.txt"
R_SCRIPT="RScript.R"
SRCPATH=$(awk -F\" -v r_script=$R_SCRIPT '/JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY/ { print $2 }' $master_file_name)

Rscript --vanilla $SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT
```

Thank you so much everyone that took the time to help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: the quotes around the path in the `masterFile` might be causing the issue, either try removing them if you can or change the awk command to ignore them

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, to get a trace as it executes. If @Mheni is right, you'll see something like `+ SRCPATH='"/path/to/source/"'`, where the single-quotes indicate that the double-quotes are literally part of the value assigned to the variable. And you'll see something similar on the `Rscript` command, again because the double-quotes are literally part of the value passed. BTW, while you don't want quotes in your data, you do want them *around* the data, e.g. use `"$master_file_name"` instead of just `$master_file_name`.

Comment: Fix `#! /bin/bash` -- there is no space in the command processor specification. Also quote `Rscript --vanilla "$SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT"` -- otherwise, if there is whitespace anywhere in the path, `$SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT` will be interpreted as multiple files.

Comment: yes @DavidC.Rankin that should be fixed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because of the quotes around the path, this change to the `awk` command ignores them when printing the path.

there was also a space in the shebang line that shouldn't be there as @david mentioned

```
#!/bin/bash

master_file_name="/tmp/data"
R_SCRIPT="RScript.R"
SRCPATH=$(awk '/JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY/ { if(NR==2) { gsub("\"",""); print $2 } }' "$master_file_name")
echo "$SRCPATH/$R_SCRIPT"
```

OUTPUT

```
[1] "Hello World!"
```

in my example the paths are in `/tmp/data`

```
NOT_DIRECTORY "/tmp/file/paths/Fake"
JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY "/tmp/file/paths/Real"
ALSO_NOT_DIRECTORY "/tmp/file/paths/Fake"
```

and in the path that corresponds to `JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY` i have a simple hello_world R script

```
[user@host tmp]$ cat /tmp/file/paths/Real/RScript.R
print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: It's not, hist use of `awk` in the *command substitution* is correct. The initial problem is with the command processor specification `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: indeed the space in the shebang line is an error but even after fixing that, the quotes still are part of the final value with his old `awk` command. the output is the following `'"/file/paths/Real"/RScript.R': No such file or directory`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Space is allowed between `#!` and the interpreter path, except by systemd. See [this question on the Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751/is-space-allowed-between-and-bin-bash-in-shebang).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ghah! Thank You. I don't know why I recall that not being allowed.I recall very clearly there being a consequence to whitespace in the interpreter line. I don't know why, and it could be from 20+ years ago too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

Master_File.txt :

```
NOT_DIRECTORY="/file/paths/Fake"
JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY="/file/paths/Real"
ALSO_NOT_DIRECTORY="/file/paths/Fake"
```

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

R_SCRIPT="RScript.R"

if [[ -r /path/to/Master_File.txt ]]; then
    . /path/to/Master_File.txt
else
    echo "ERROR -- Can't read Master_File"
    exit
fi

Rscript --vanilla $JOB_TEST_DIRECTORY/$R_SCRIPT
```

Basically, you create a configuration file Key=value, source it then use the the keys as variable for whatever you need throughout the script.